# Transcription of short spoken sentences.

Tags: listening

1) ___을울리는 
https://clyp.it/j1vdorlg

2) 현실적인 ____
https://clyp.it/ve2rzsc5

3) 리듬_____ 불구하고 
https://clyp.it/c5xqlf34

4) 너무 나도 ____ 감사합니다
https://clyp.it/54nvwrvz

5)  연습생이 ___으로  가져간거같습니다.
https://clyp.it/fxdlhrpf

6) 일본어 소통에도 ____
https://clyp.it/qofxebz1

7) 또 ____항상 저를 응원
https://clyp.it/qvto5nqa

8) 아쉬움을 _____
https://clyp.it/fagsyjbh

9)  왜 없어있지_____
https://clyp.it/gv3gxwfa

I don't need the whole thing transcribed. I just can't catch the specific words.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I listen to speech in languages of which I'm not native, the most frustrating thing that gets me total crazy is a mismatch between sound and the corresponding text. I feel you so bad, so I transcribed everything in a literal sense.

---

- 정말　**심금**을　울리는　무대였습니다.

  심금: heartstring.

---

- 걸　그룹의　선배로서　현실적인　**조언을　아끼지　않았던　우리**―　소유　트레이너　쌤!

  It's getting faster as more words pop up from his mouth. And, there comes a short pause right before introducing the name of the person. 쌤: a person that teaches someone (a famous slang, from the 대구 dialect.).

---

- 아,　누구나　따라할　수　있는　어떤　경쾌한　리듬――**의　곡임**에도　불구하고,

  A delayed speech.

---

- **너…… ……하겠습니다.**

  **WHAT???**

---

- 연습생이　**부상**으로　가져간　거　같습니다.

  부상: additional prize. He's just joking.

---

- 일본어　소통에도　앞장**서　주셨**잖아요.

  The honorific part is super fast. I feel you.

---

- 또,　**보이지　않는　곳**에서　항상　절　응원해　주시는

  A typical Special-thanks speech.

---

- <sub>이제</sub>　새록새록,　<sub>어,</sub>　생각이　나고,　아쉬움을　**뒤로해야　하는,　<sub>이제,</sub>　순간이**　다가오고　있는　것　같습니다.

  A bunch of filler words.
  이제: now. 어: uh.

---

- 아이,　**왜　없어?　있지.　우리도　있는데.**

  A short interrogative expression for emphasizing his strong supposition. Thus no pause between it and its following sentence.

Comment: on reddit someone said https://www.reddit.com/r/Korean/comments/9dk666/could_someone_transcribe_what_theyre_saying/  for number 4 it's 앞장서셨잖아요. so are both possible?

Comment: @gdgdgdgd Since “-시-” in the “셨” is an honorific as well, both, one omitting “주다” and one not, are possible with no problem. It's just I hear a slight /j/ sound in-between.

Answer (score 1):

1. 심금
2. 조언을 아끼지 않았던 우리 소유 트레이너 샘
3. (리듬)에 곡(? not clear)임에도 (불구하고)
4. 흐뭇(? not clear)하였습니다 (or she mispronounced)
5. 부상 ('부상' is an additional prize)
6. 앞장 서셨잖아요? 예, 그랬죠.
7. 보이지 않는 곳에서
8. 뒤로해야 하는 순간이 다가오고 있는것 같습니다.
9. 우리도 있는데